# Как работает этот метод сортировки код?

Tags: delphi

Это код сортировки одномерного массива на delphi.

Массив из 15 до этого случайно введенных элементов.

Помогите пожалуйста понять зачем тут два цикла.

Я понимаю этот код так:
В цикле мы перебираем массив arr сравниваем текущий элемент с следующим и выполняем перестановку в зависимости от результата, но почему два цикла?

```
for i:= 1 to 15 do
    for j:= 1 to 14 do
      if arr[j] > arr[j+1] then
        begin
          x:= arr[j+1];
          arr[j+1]:= arr[j];
          arr[j]:= x;
        end;
```

Comment: Похоже на пузырьковую сортировку... Если будет один цикл, то элемент сможет передвинуться только на одну позицию. Очевидно, что для сортировки этого недостаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим на примере:

Крайний случай для этого алгоритма - элементы отсортированы в обратном порядке, т.е.

`arr = (15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)`

Уберем внешний цикл (по `i`), выполним внутренний (по `j`) 1 раз, и получим:

`arr = (14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 15)`

т.е. максимальный элемент может смещаться вправо сразу на своё место, а вот минимальный влево - только на одну позицию.

Поэтому и нужно внешний цикл, т.к. минимальный влево нужно сдвинуть через весь массив.

Есть два замечания:

1. Внешний цикл (по `i`) достаточно выполнять `N-1` (14) раз, так как именно столько действий нужно чтобы сместить элемент из одного края в другой.
2. Т.к. на каждой итерации `i` самых больших элементов оказываются на своих местах, то внутренний достаточно выполнять только для первых `N-i` элементов.

PS Для простой сортировки нужно сравнить каждый элемент с каждый, т.е. порядка N*N сравнений. Вложенные циклы как раз и дают такой порядок количества действий.